# Converting Scheme into OCaml? ('a list vs 'a list list -> 'a list list)

Tags: scheme, ocaml

```
(define min
   (lambda (l)
      (cond
         ((null? l) '())
         ((null? (cdr l)) (car l))
         (#t (let ((a (car l))
                   (b (min (cdr l))))
               (if (< b a) b a))))))
```

I'm trying to convert the preceeding Scheme code which finds the smallest element in a list into OCaml code and I have the following so far:

```
let minList x =
   match x with
   | [] -> []
   | hd::tl when tl = [] -> hd
   | hd::tl -> if minList tl < hd then minList tl else hd
```

However, I am getting an error that says "This expression has type 'a list but an expression was expected of type `'a list list -> 'a list list`.

I am a beginner to functional language and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is a difference from the type system.

With Scheme, the function can output a number or an empty list.

```
> (min `(1 2 3))
1

> (min `())
()
```

With OCaml you cannot, the output has to be of the same type. You can read more about type inference in [Real World Ocaml](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/a-guided-tour.html).

You do not want to return an int from an empty list, you want to fail.

What you can do is to use the option type, so that the function output `None` from an empty list and, `Some 'a` from a non empty `'a list`.
Thus the type of the function will be `'a list -> 'a option`.

And BTW, the case `| hd::tl when tl = [] -> hd` can be simplified to  `| [x] -> x`.
As when `tl = []`, `hd::tl = hd::[] = [hd]`.

Answer (score 0):

I see two errors in your code :

1. Your function is recursive so you need to add the keyword `rec` to your function like this `let rec minList x`
2. Your function should have the type `'a list -> 'a` but because in the first pattern matching you are returning a list, you are getting this error. Because you are working with `'a list'`, maybe it can be good to keep the first element of the list and then if at the end, the list is empty then return this first element (which is the min of the list).